# Sharing ViewModel for Fragments in ViewPager2 or create a new one for every Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-mvvm, android-viewpager2

I have a dilemma how to implement a particular functionality. I need to display a list of pages, where each page has its own list of sections.

The way how it is now implemented, i have an Activity and a Fragment that have reference to the same ViewModel. From the NavigationDrawer when i select a concrete page, i change the list of sections that is displayed in the Fragment. The LiveData attributes are shown in the snippet.

```
public LiveData<List<Page>> pages;
public MutableLiveData<Page> selectedPage = new MutableLiveData<>(new Page(1));
public LiveData<List<Section>> sections = Transformations.switchMap(this.selectedPage, (Page page) ->
    this.pageRepository.getSectionsForPage(page.id)
);
```

Now, besides the NavigationDrawer, i wanted to add swipe possibility of changing pages, and that led me to using ViewPager. But because that leads to using multiple Fragments of the same type, i'm wondering if using a shared ViewModel for every instance is a good option? In that way, every fragment shows totally the same data. The other way would be to make a new specific ViewModel for every instance, which i'm not sure if it is a good idea, because i can probably have as many as 50 pages.

A lot of pages possibility is maybe also not a use case for a ViewPager, but i'm not sure about that, because my Android experience is low.

Any tip with an explanation why is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sharedViewModel then it will be attached to activity ........ if you are using separate viewModel then it is attached with the lifeCycle of Fragment

Comment: Yeah, i understand that, but what are the pros and cons of both cases? Is one particularly better than the other in this specific occasion.

Comment: Depends of the need if you need to pass data between two fragments then you can use sharedView Model and if you have no connections between fragments then to make the code separate you can have different viewModels